# Can I glue a MagSafe connector broken at the "computer" end?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, repair, magsafe

On the left is what I have; wire part on the left, broken off part on the right. The right is what I would like.

[image]
[image]

I can just take the broken off part and hold it against the wire part to make it the same as first picture.  It works to get power to the computer but it keeps coming off depending on the angle I try to remove from the computer.  Anyone here have an idea if it's possible to glue or fix it?

Comment: Are you saying that it will work if you hold the parts in place by hand?  If so, I would suggest using a non destructive method of fixing it, such as a small rubber band.  Can you take the parts to an Apple store or service centre?  If  it were me, and nothing else worked, I would try glue, once again initially choosing a type that was non destructive.

Comment: I wonder if we could edit your question to make the pictures smaller?

Comment: @DAVincent is it possible to do it using the builtin markdown? I didn't know that, sorry.

Comment: > Are you saying that it will work if you hold the parts in place by hand? Yes, it works flawlessly. Would soldering be a good idea?

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I'll take the liberty of editing the question.

Comment: If it were me I would try with some small rubber bands.  As for soldering, I would first try and find out what metals the parts are made of, and prepare to be disappointed - I wouldn't be surprised if Apple have used some unusual alloys.

Comment: @DAVincent - just a note... you can resize an existing image by using the format <img src="[copy/paste from original]" width="280">

Comment: @Tetsujin That's a great tip! Thanks for sharing. :)

Comment: @Tetsujin ditto (and I have clicked on the up arrow next to your comment) (and nice work on the formatting)

Comment: Clean it with acetone (nail polish remover); use a q-tip if necessary.  You want to make sure it's clean.   When dry use a ***small*** amount of super glue around the edges.  Hold for about a minute and you will be good to go.

Comment: @Allan are you suggesting something like this? https://www.amazon.com/Loctite-Bonder-442-49550-Instant-Adhesive/dp/B00065UAH2

Comment: That should work.

Comment: @Allan, I've used the superglue since the day of your suggestion and not having problems so far. Would you mind giving your suggestion as an answer instead of a comment so I could mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed with an application of Super Glue or other adhesive for metals.

First, clean it with acetone - use a cotton swab (like a Q-Tip) to ensure that the metal is clean.  This will help the adhesive bond properly

Using a small amount of adhesive that is made for bonding metals like [Super Glue](http://radnex.us/Loctite-Super-Glue-Adhesive), place it around the edges of the part to be repaired.  Hold for at least a minute (the set time for the adhesive) and you should be good.  For best results, allow to cure for an hour before use.  You should be good to go